# Python Crash Course - 13-5 Sideways Shooter Pt 2, Adding the aliens

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I managed the first part of this exercise, back in chapter 12, without any problems, but now that I'm trying to add aliens into the mix, I've run into trouble.

I can't get them to draw in at the top right of the screen, they keep starting at the top left; and they aren't moving at all.

Everything else seems to be working just fine, including ship movement and bullet collision.

So, how do I get the aliens to draw in starting at the top right, in columns, and have them move up and down?

*sideways_shooter.py*

```
import sys
from time import sleep

import pygame

from settings import Settings
from game_stats import GameStats
from ship import Ship
from bullet import Bullet
from alien import Alien

class SidewaysShooter:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sideways Shooter")

        self.stats = GameStats(self)

        self.ship = Ship(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()

        self._create_fleet()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            self._check_events()

            if self.stats.game_active:
                self.ship.update()
                self._update_bullets()
                #self._update_aliens()

            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        #Respond to keypresses and mouse events
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)

    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        #Respond to keypresses
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            self._fire_bullet()

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        #Respond to key releases
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.ship.moving_up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.ship.moving_down = False

    def _update_aliens(self):
        #Check if the fleet is at an edge, update the position of all the aliens
        self._check_fleet_edges()
        self.aliens.update()

        #Check for alien-ship collisions
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(self.ship, self.aliens):
            self._ship_hit()

        #Look for aliens hitting the bottom
        self._check_aliens_bottom()

    def _fire_bullet(self):
        #Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group
        if len(self.bullets) < self.settings.bullets_allowed:
            new_bullet = Bullet(self)
            self.bullets.add(new_bullet)

    def _update_bullets(self):
        #Update position of bullets and get rid of old bullets
        #Update bullet positions
        self.bullets.update()

        #Get rid of bullets that have left the screen
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.left >= self.settings.screen_width:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)

        self._check_bullet_alien_collisions()

    def _check_bullet_alien_collisions(self):
        #Respond to alien bullet collsions
        #Remove any bullets and aliens that have collided

        collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(
            self.bullets, self.aliens, True, True)

        if not self.aliens:
            #Destroy existing bullets and create new fleet
            self.bullets.empty()
            self._create_fleet()


    def _update_screen(self):
        #Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()

        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    def _create_fleet(self):
        #Create the fleet of aliens
        #Make an alien and find the number of aliens in a column
        #Spacing between each alien should be equal to one alien height
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        available_space_y = self.settings.screen_height - (2 * alien_height)
        number_aliens_y = available_space_y // (2 * alien_height)

        #Determine the number of columns that can fit on the screen
        ship_width = self.ship.rect.width
        available_space_x = (self.settings.screen_width -
                                (4 * alien_width) - ship_width)
        number_rows = available_space_x // (2 * alien_width)

        #Create the full fleet of aliens
        for row_number in range(number_rows):
            for alien_number in range(number_aliens_y):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)

    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        #Create an alien and place it in the column
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        alien.y = alien_height + 2 * alien_height * alien_number
        alien.rect.y = alien.y
        alien.rect.x = alien.rect.width + 2 * alien.rect.width * row_number
        self.aliens.add(alien) 

    def _check_fleet_edges(self):
        #Respond appropriately if any aliens have reached an edge
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.check_edges():
                self._change_fleet_direction()
                break

    def _change_fleet_direction(self):
        #Drop the entire fleet and change direction
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            alien.rect.x += self.settings.fleet_drop_speed
        self.settings.fleet_direction *= -1

    def _check_aliens_bottom(self):
        #Check if any aliens have reached the left of the screen
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        for alien in self.aliens.sprites():
            if alien.rect.left >= screen_rect.left:
                #Treat this the same as if the ship was hit
                self._ship_hit()
                break

    def _ship_hit(self):
        #Respond to the ship being hit by an alien
        if self.stats.ships_left > 0:
            #Decrement ships_left
            self.stats.ships_left -= 1

            #Get rid of any remaining aliens and bullets            
            self.aliens.empty()
            self.bullets.empty()

            #Create a new fleet and center the ship
            self._create_fleet()
            self.ship.center_ship()

            #Pause
            sleep(0.5)

        else:
            self.stats.game_active = False 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Make a game instance, and run the game
    ai = SidewaysShooter()
    ai.run_game()
```

*alien.py*

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite

class Alien(Sprite):
    #A class to represent an alien

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        #Initialize the alien and set its starting position
        super().__init__()
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.settings = ai_game.settings

        #Load the alien image and set its rect attribute
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/alien.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #Start each new alien near the top right of the screen
        self.rect.x = self.settings.screen_width - self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #Store the alien's exact vertical position
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def check_edges(self):
        #Return True if alien is at the edge of screen
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        if self.rect.bottom >= screen_rect.bottom or self.rect.top <= 0:
            return True

    def update(self):
        #Move the alien up or down
        self.y += (self.settings.alien_speed *
                    self.settings.fleet_direction)
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

Comment: Apologies, my first question so I went overzealous with the amount of code posted in retrospect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your aliens are appearing on the left side of the screen because of this line:

```py
alien.rect.x = alien.rect.width + 2 * alien.rect.width * row_number
```

When the row number is 0, the second term here is 0, and the alien's x position will be equal to its width.

If you want them to start appearing on the right side of the screen, you can make its initial position equal to the screen width minus a certain amount, like a multiple of the alien's width.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the problem of them starting in the incorrect position! I still need to figure out how to make them move, but hopefully I can figure that much out on my own now that this is out of the way.